# How to locally link library and avoid conflicts?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating a React Native library to use for RN apps. How do I link this library to use in a test app without publishing to npm?

Only trying the Android build right now (iOS not finished). I've tried `npm install /path/to/lib/`, `react-native install /path/to/lib/`, `npm link /path/to/lib`, `npm pack` and linking that, and adding the lib through git.

Comment: Have you tried manually add the library files in your app.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I tried that and the test app recognizes it, but this is meant to be a library for third parties